# Can't find wifi settings in hera

Tags: wifi, release-hera

[image]

I can't find wifi setting in hera. I install it dual boot with windows.. any solution? Please help

Comment: Please include details about what hardware you have, including the model of your WiFi adapter if you know this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to shut down (not restart from window$) when dual booting and see if that helps. I got no sound when I directly restarted from Window$... Shuting down first solved the issue.